# How can I change the data types of multiple dataframe columns based on a condition in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 80 columns, for some columns data types should be integers but python sees them as float. Rather than manually changing the data types I am trying to write a loop that identifies the datatype that a column contains and changes the data type accordingly. I have tried the following options but it did not provide any results:

1) I tried to take columns as a variable and if the datatype is float convert it to integer.

```py
for x in data1.columns:
    if isinstance(data1.columns,float):
        data1[x]=data1[x].astype('int')
```

2) I also tried this

```py
for x in data1.columns:
    if x isinstance(x,float):
        data1=data1.astype(int)
    else:
        break
```

My general question is is it possible to change column datatypes with a loop, condition, function etc.?

Before posting a question I researched the web, most of the questions about changing individual column's datatype.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: What happens when you run the proposed code?

Comment: Can you format the code for readability?

Comment: I apologize, I did not notice the code was messed up, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5.,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1.8,3.3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5.0,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
print (df)
   A    B  C    D    E  F
0  a  4.0  7  1.8  5.0  a
1  b  5.0  8  3.3  3.0  a
2  c  4.0  9  5.0  6.0  a
3  d  5.0  4  7.0  9.0  b
4  e  5.0  2  1.0  2.0  b
5  f  4.0  3  0.0  4.0  b
```

Idea is filter only numeric columns first by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and then get all integers and integers columns like floats (`0` after decimal) by compare by converted columns to integers and filter all matched columns by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), filter them, create dictionary and pass to [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
d = dict.fromkeys(df1.columns[df1.eq(df1.astype(int)).all()], 'int')

df = df.astype(d)
print (df)
   A  B  C    D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1.8  5  a
1  b  5  8  3.3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5.0  6  a
3  d  5  4  7.0  9  b
4  e  5  2  1.0  2  b
5  f  4  3  0.0  4  b
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1.eq(df1.astype(int)))
      B     C      D     E
0  True  True  False  True
1  True  True  False  True
2  True  True   True  True
3  True  True   True  True
4  True  True   True  True
5  True  True   True  True

print (df1.columns[df1.eq(df1.astype(int)).all()])
Index(['B', 'C', 'E'], dtype='object')

print (d)
{'B': 'int', 'C': 'int', 'E': 'int'}
```

If want set all floats columns to integers - your loop solution:

```
for x in data1.columns:
    if isinstance(data1[x].iat[0],float):
        data1[x]=data1[x].astype(int)

print (data1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Non loop solution:

```
data1 = data1.astype(dict.fromkeys(data1.select_dtypes(np.floating), 'int'))
print (data1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the data is a household-level survey that we conducted in order to measure the COVID-19's financial impact on refugee household. I thought about filtering the numeric columns but I prefer not to create another data frame, change datatype and then merge with the original data frame if it is possible to create a loop.

Comment: @AlperenAçıkol - Hmmm, so you need loops? What is reason? Because in pandas are really not recommended. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002).

Comment: @jezael It is not necessarily a need, I was trying to solve the problem with a loop because I did not want to deal with creating a dictionary for 40+ columns, but after reading the post you pointed out I decided to stick with the proposed solution.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I checked the code it solved my problem thank you, man. I just have one question, you introduced iat[0] what does it do exactly?

Comment: @AlperenAçıkol - It get first value of column and check if float